# How to define an automatically unfoldable definition

Tags: coq

I sometimes want to define some shortcut for existing functions like in the following example:

```
Parameter T : Set.
Parameter zero one: T.
Parameter f : T -> T -> option T.
Hypothesis f_unit : forall t, f zero t = None.

Definition g (t : T) := f t one.
```

However, this definition seems to be abstract since I cannot use theorems about `f` on instances of `g` without first unfolding:

```
Goal (g zero = None).
  unfold g.
  rewrite f_unit.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Is there a way to mark definitions as automatically unfoldable?

Comment: Yes, I would like not to have to manually `unfold`.

Comment: You could allow `simpl` to expand the definition of `g` by declaring `Arguments g t /.`

Comment: Or define `g` as a "parsing-only" shorthand notation instead of a function.  Something like: `Notation "'g' t" := (f t one) (at level 0, parsing only).`

Comment: Or `Hint Unfold g.` and then use `autounfold` tactic in the proof.

Comment: Also, ssreflect can do it with with context patterns: `Require Import ssreflect. ` then your goal can be proved by `by rewrite [g _]f_unit.`. This `[g _]` pattern makes `rewrite` to unfold the definition of `g`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to accomplish what you ask, and here is an explanation of the ones I know:

---

1. Use an abbreviation.  To quote [the reference manual](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/syntax-extensions.html#Abbreviations):

   > An *abbreviation* is a name, possibly applied to arguments, that denotes a (presumably) more complex expression.
   >
   > [...]
   >
   > Abbreviations are bound to an absolute name as an ordinary definition is, and they can be referred by qualified names too.
   >
   > Abbreviations are syntactic in the sense that they are bound to expressions which are not typed at the time of the definition of the abbreviation but at the time it is used.

In your case, this would be

```
Notation g t := (f t one).
```

This is much like Daniel Schepler's suggestion of a `Notation`, except that it does not reserve `g` as a global keyword.

---

2. Use `setoid_rewrite`.  Coq's `setoid_rewrite` tactic is similar to `rewrite`, except that it looks for occurrences modulo δ (unfolding), can rewrite under binders, and a few other minor things.

For your example, this is:

```
Require Import Coq.Setoids.Setoid.
Goal (g zero = None).
Proof.
  setoid_rewrite f_unit.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

---

3. In some cases, you can use `Set Keyed Unification` and `Declare Equivalent Keys`, though this does not work in your case (I've opened an issue [on GitHub here](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/6317).  This tells `rewrite` to "unfold" one head constant to another, though it apparently isn't quite good enough to handle your case.  There's a bit of documentation [on the relevant commit message](https://github.com/coq/coq/commit/3fe4912b568916676644baeb982a3e10c592d887), and an [open issue to add proper documentation](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/4551).

Here is an example this is useful:

```
Parameter T : Set.
Parameter zero one: T.
Parameter f : T -> T -> option T.
Hypothesis f_unit : forall t, f zero t = None.

Definition g := f zero zero.

Set Keyed Unification.
Goal (g = None).
Proof.
  Fail rewrite f_unit.
  Declare Equivalent Keys g f.
  rewrite f_unit.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```